# Rotating bone changes size

Tags: armature, bones

When I rotate a bone, the size of the bone changes. Any idea how to fix this?

[.blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7psawyxh1w6egaf/scout.blend?dl=0)

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you rotate the bone in edit mode or pose mode?

Comment: @David Pose Mode

Comment: It looks like the bone's parent is scaled in a single axis, meaning that this bone will appear to change size when rotate against the axis of the parent's scale.

Comment: @Poyo If I turn off "Inherit Scale" in the rotating bone, it still changes size.

Comment: @Poyo any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @chris I think you might have to upload a .blend.

Comment: @Poyo https://www.dropbox.com/s/7psawyxh1w6egaf/scout.blend?dl=0

Comment: @chris I was close. The bone's parent is not scaled, it's the whole armature that's scaled.

Comment: @Poyo So how do I fix this?

Comment: @chris Reset the scale of the armature by selecting it and pressing `Alt+S`.

Comment: @Poyo, or ctrl+A and scale (depending on what you want)

Comment: Chris, understand that this behavior is normal : your armarture is 2.8 times greater in Z than X or Y. So when things which were in Z come to X or Y, they become thinner.

Answer (score 2):

I have the fix. It is so easy. Select your rig in object mode and apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*.